# Bootstrap Collapse Is Not Closing When Click on Nav Button

Tags: jquery

Collapse is not closing when I click on `nav Button`. It's working on the home page only. when I try to do that on another page (navigation-page) it's not working. how can I solve it?

Note: As per my check-in inspect its closing but immediately again `show` the collapse `menu-item`. I'm not getting how to fix this.

HTML

```html
<header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LOGO </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-menu" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav-menu">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item" >
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#" data-page="about">About Us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#" data-page="work">Our Work</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#" data-page="tech">Tech</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#" data-page="process">Our Process</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item" >
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#" data-page="blog">Blog</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <div id="body-content">

    </div>
```

JS

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".navbar-collapse .navbar-nav li a").click(function(){
        $("li").removeClass("active");
        $(this).closest("li").addClass("active");
        $(".collapse").collapse('hide');
        $("#body-content").load($(this).data("page")+".html");
    });
});
```

Comment: I created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dkorber/eapy41cn/2/), but was not able to reproduce the problem. It is working fine... There may be another script doing that.

Comment: I'm using this  '                                                                                              
                                                                                                                   
  '<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>'
 '<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
> </script>'
 '<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js></script>'